# R: Downloading a .csv from a website

Tags: javascript, r, download, href, export-to-csv

I'm trying to have R automatically download a .csv file from FanGraphs to a local directory.  To do this manually, I have to click on the "Export Data" link, whereby javascript is called for me to download the .csv file.  I've used Rvest before,  but I'm not sure how to complete this task.  The .csv file is very orderly once downloaded manually.

Here is the link:

```
url <- "http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=y&type=8&season=2016&month=0&season1=2016&ind=0"
```

Here is the link to the download:

```
href="javascript:__doPostBack('LeaderBoard1$cmdCSV','')"
```

I'm stumped and would appreciate any help!  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To load data from a HTTP source in R, use:

```
con <- url("http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~zanoni/cepagri/cepagri.csv") 
cpa <- read.csv(con)
```

I tried your URL, but I got a 404 Not Found:

```
u <- "http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspxpos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=y&type=15&season=2016&month=0&season1=2016&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0"

con <- url(u) 
cpa <- read.csv(con)  


Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  cannot open URL     'http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspxpos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=y&type=15&season=2016&month=0&season1=2016&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

Comment: The link is an html page with lots of data on it, but not formatted for straight reading to .csv format.  Clicking on the "export data" link executes javascript to produce a .csv file for download.  When I put my cursor over the "Export Data" link, the link is `href="javascript:__doPostBack('LeaderBoard1$cmdCSV','')"`

Comment: This is a java script call to process something, in the end, there is a URL that is called. If you are using Google Chrome, open the developer inspect and check the network tab and try to find out what is the URL called by this method.

Answer (score 0):

if you use linux, you can also use wget to download the file and import it in R

```
    $wget "www.yourURL.com"
```